# setPersistance crash in some devices

Tags: android, firebase, crash, try-catch, firebase-realtime-database

As the title says, I use Firebase and I use the instruction "setPersistance" to save the user data offline. I've wrote this instruction in the splash screen of my app, this way I'm sure that I never call other instance of Firebase before. But I don't know why it crash on some devices, the log says:

> Calls to setPersistenceEnabled() must be made before any other usage of FirebaseDatabase instance.

Exist some try catch() to avoid this crashes?

Comment: It's impossible to say much without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But in general the solution is to do what [other developers who encountered this error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D++Calls+to+setPersistenceEnabled%28%29+must+be+made+before+any+other+usage+of+FirebaseDatabase+instance.) did. The answers here looks especially promising: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448186/setpersistenceenabledtrue-crashes-app

Comment: You can use one of the 2 first answers in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753991/com-google-firebase-database-databaseexception-calls-to-setpersistenceenabled/37766261#37766261