# Error after logout and try to login again on Firebase DB

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app is working normally but he crash if i logout and try to login again. After the crash if i try to open the app again he open normally.

This is the error:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Calls to setPersistenceEnabled() must be made before any other usage of FirebaseDatabase instance.
```

This is my classe:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference;

RecyclerView recyclerView;
ArrayList<Tasks> tasksArrayList;
UsersRecyclerAdapter adapter;

GoogleSignInOptions gso;
GoogleSignInClient gsc;

String userID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar());

    CheckLogin();

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true); // work offline
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    tasksArrayList = new ArrayList<>();



    ReadData();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.add) {
        ViewDialogAdd viewDialogAdd = new ViewDialogAdd();
        viewDialogAdd.showDialog(MainActivity.this);
    }else if (id == R.id.logout) {
        gsc.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void CheckLogin(){
    //Check if user is logged in
    gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    gsc = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
    if (account != null){
        userID = account.getId();
    } else {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}

private void ReadData() {

    if (userID != null) {
        databaseReference.child("DB").child(userID).child("TASKS").orderByChild("id").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    tasksArrayList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Tasks users = dataSnapshot.getValue(Tasks.class);
                        tasksArrayList.add(users);
                    }
                    adapter = new UsersRecyclerAdapter(MainActivity.this, tasksArrayList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

}

public class ViewDialogAdd {
    public void showDialog(Context context) {
        /*Body*/
    }
}
```

I tried to change this line of code:

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

I put it in different places in my code but the error is the same.
I also tried to remove the CheckLogin(); but the error persist the same way

Comment: Are you using `setPersistenceEnabled` in other parts of your app?

Comment: No, i was only using in the MainActivity

Comment: So even of you're only using `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);`, you get the same error message?

Comment: Yes. I already solved the problem using a guide i found. Thank you for try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday i make a few researches about my error and found nothing. Today i made i few more searches and this here helped me fix the problem.

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37551156)